# Help! problem encounter when exporting animation (with constraint)

Tags: rigging, export

I am having trouble exporting my animation to as a glb/fbx. I have use 'damped track" and  "locked track" bone constraint to speed up my animation.

The problem occur when I tried to export my animation, the exported animation is unable to loop even tough the animation is perfectly fine when view from blender. Even baking then animation would not solve the problem.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? I would like to kept the constraint.

the blend is provided

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for bake the rig animation, in pose mode, select all bones, then in the bake action dialog you need cheek "Visual Keying", "Clear Constraints" and "Overwrite Current Action", that creates keyframes without any constraints that gltf files can't handle

[image]

[image]

Now you can export to gltf and view the results.

[image]

Comment: Leonardo Caceres, thank you for replying. But the method you provided doesn't work for my case.  If I bake with "Clear Constraint" ticked, The baked animation will end up not being the same as the prebake animation. 


In prebake animation(with constraint) the animation at frame 60 is  able loop with frame 1, however after baking , both frame will ended up with different pose, making the animation loop always end with a quick cut.

Comment: if you want to get a loop animation, with all the bones selected, you can select the last keyframes and delete them, then select and duplicate the first column of keyframes and move them to the end of the animation.

Comment: I have tried , it doesn't work though. the "quick cut" will still persist...

Comment: I see the problem, to fix this, you can duplicate the entire animation twice, set the end range of animation to 120 to cover all animation, then with all bones selected bake the action. Now you have the loop animation in the range of 60 to 120, delete rest of keyframes before export. [Preview of process](https://imgur.com/a/4hciEmK)

Comment: Sorry, imgur not accept APNG for preview, [here the video of process](https://imgur.com/a/HWDHJYy)

Comment: Thank you so much, really. I have been trying to figure it for a long time. Thank you