# Bat is off of the batsman when exported to GLB

Tags: animation, rigging, export

I did an animation of a batsman, after I export into GLB Format, here the bat is off of the batsman.

I tried child of parenting and also created a handle and parented the bat to the bone and again added constraint.

How to solve this?

[image: Before Export]
[image: After Export]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276073/help-problem-encounter-when-exporting-animation-with-constraint (Glb export doesn't export Blender's constraints.)